# Extract NSArray of dictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I am having a response data as below .I have an array populated by dictionaries, and I need to sort last two values from each index of multi dimensional array.

This is my array:

arrayListstatus

```
(

    {

    "Applicant_FirstName" = "";
    "Applicant_LastName" = "";
    "Application_ID" = test;
    "Application_Status" = "";
},
    {
    "Applicant_FirstName" = John;
    "Applicant_LastName" = Doe;
    "Application_ID" = 0002;
    "Application_Status" = Recertify;
}
)
```

Here is my code:

```
- (NSArray *)subItems

{

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int ar = 0; ar < arrayListstatus.count; ar++)

{
    NSArray *thirdarray=[arrayListstatus objectAtIndex:ar] ;


    NSLog(@"thirdarray %@",third array);


    [items addObject:thirdarray];

}

NSLog(@"itemss %@",items);

return items;


}
```

Comment: What do you mean under sorted? You need to put it into a third array, and then sort by which attribute? Id or status?

Comment: There has been nothing new for the past several years as far as this subject is concerned.

Comment: I need to sort out both .It should look like   { "Application_ID" = test;
    "Application_Status" = "";},{
   "Application_ID" = 0002;
    "Application_Status" = Recertify;
}

Comment: By "sort", do you mean "extract specific keys"?  Could you amend your question to include the exact output you desire?

Comment: Sorry,ya i have to extract last two values from the each index.Please can u help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this should do the trick:

```
- (NSArray *)subItems

{

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int ar = 0; ar < arrayListstatus.count; ar++)

{

   NSArray *thirdarray= [arrayListstatus objectAtIndex:ar] ;
NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDict setObject:[thirdarray objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"Application_ID"];
 [tmpDict setObject:[thirdarray objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"Application_Status"];

[items addObject:tmpDict];

    [items addObject:tmpDict];

}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor =  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:"Application_Status" ascending:YES], nil]];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];




NSLog(@"itemss %@",items);

return items;


}
```

Comment: how we can use set object inside array.It is showing error in [tmpDict setObject:[thirdarray setObject:2] forKey:@"Application_ID"];
     [tmpDict setObject:[thirdarray setObject:3] forKey:@"Application_Status"];.

Comment: actually, the returned object from arrayListstatus will return a dictionary not an array, right? I have edited according to this.

Comment: No,it will return array not a dictionary

Comment: ok, than i have changed it back, it should be objectAtIndex, not setObject.